# How do I remember a variable referenced in an earlier function in a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading the contents for 1) a sidebar and 2) a main content area. Each of these areas have their own set of navigation links that should load new content in its respective area.

If I press a link in the sidebar, the sidebar's contents should update without refreshing the main content area. Likewise, if I press a link in the main content area, it should refresh that content area, but leave the sidebar alone. My goal is to be able to just update each area when a user explicitly decides they want to update that portion of the page.

Here the my javascript I'm using to load both content area's navigation links and update each respective area.

```
//Get the sidebar's navigation links and display them
$.get("sidebar-navigation.html", function(data){
    $(".sidebar-nav").html(data);
  });

/*
When I click on a link in the sidebar, load the new page in
ONLY the sidebar, without refreshing the main area.

Use $.on() to associate a click handler with any link nested 
under .sidebar-navigation, 
even if the links are dynamically added to the page in the 
future (ie after a 
$.get())
*/

$('body').on('click', '.sidebar-nav a', function() {

/*
  Get the href for the link being clicked
*/
  var href = $(this).attr('href');

/*
Issue a request for the html document
or resource at href and load the contents
directly into .sidebar if successful
*/

$('.sidebar-content').load(href);

/*
Return false to prevent the link's default
navigation behavior
*/
return false;
})

//Get the main content area's navigation and display it

$.get("navigation.html", function(data){
  $(".nav-placeholder").html(data);
});

/*How do I set a function to call the last visible page, rather 
than a static page in the sidebar?
I want to reference the variable 'href' up above to load the same
contents, even if I click on another link in the main content area
*/

$.get("href", function(data){
  $(".sidebar").html(data);
});

/*
Load a page in the main content area
*/

$('body').on('click', '.nav-placeholder a', function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.body-container').load(href);
  return false;
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"even if I click on another link in the main content area"_? Is `$.get("href", function(data){
  $(".sidebar").html(data);
})` expected to be executed more than once?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the clearest comment. I don't want to execute it more than once. I just want to pull up the last page that was loaded in the sidebar, regardless of what page is selected in the other content area. However, when I press on another page in the main content area, the sidebar is getting wiped out.

Comment: Katherine, recommend you add you HTML here as well and maybe get an answer. Any reason for using jQuery? is it just for the easier load?

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to only execute

```
$.get(<href>, function(data){
  $(".sidebar").html(data);
})
```

at most once you can define a function which accepts a single parameter `href`, define a `$.Callbacks()` object with `'once'` set as the flag pass the function to `callbacks.add()` then call `callbacks.fire` within `.load()` callback

```
// defined outside of `click` handler attached to `'body'`
const callbacks = $.Callbacks('once');
const getOnce = href => 
  $.get(href, function(data){
    $(".sidebar").html(data);
  });
callbacks.add(getOnce);
```

within `click` handler set at

```
$('.sidebar-content').load(href, function(data) {
  $(this).html(data);
  if (!callbacks.fired()) {
    callbacks.fire(href)
  }
});
```